# Как сделать пропуск слайда Bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть слайд со скрытыми блоками на больших размерах экранов(на маленьких будут отображаться), как можно пропускать пустой слайд на больших экранах?

```css
.carousel-inner {
  background: url(../img/bgsl.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hidden {
  display: none!important;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 3vh;
  margin-right: 3vh;
}

.slideritem {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  width: 18%;
  margin: 1vh!important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-width: 1px!important;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
      <p><span class="txttop">Мы предоставляем  Вам сервис,<br>
а не просто продаем по вкусным ценам!</span></p>
      <p><span class="mainhtext">Примеры цен на металочерепицу от 50м<sup>2</sup>:</span></p>
      <a href=""><img src="img/arrowbottom.png" class="img-fluid imgarr"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div id="carousel-example-1z" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="bottom: -50px;">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="0" class="active" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="1" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="2" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="3" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" class="hidden" data-slide-to="3" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin-top: 2vh;">
      <!--First slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item active text-center">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/sl1.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem" style="">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/sl2.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem" style="">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/First slide-->
      <!--Second slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Second slide-->
      <!--Third slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item text-center">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item text-center hidden">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Third slide-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img-fluid arrleft" src="img/arrowbottom.jpg"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/arrowbottom.jpg"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <button class="btn_top">Хочу все цены</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, можно сделать 2 слайдера: для маленьких(small-slider) и большых екранов(big-slider) и с помощью Media Queries прятать их в зависимости от разрешения

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .big-slider {
    display:none;
  }
 .small-slider {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Так же можно все оставить в одном слайдере но пометить класами большые(big-slide) и малые(small-slide) слайды.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .big-slide {
    display:none;
  }
 .small-slide {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Как по мне то 1 вариант лучше и правильней.

Вот что еще можно сделать

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.carousel-inner {
  background: url(../img/bgsl.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hidden {
  display: none!important;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 3vh;
  margin-right: 3vh;
}

.slideritem {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  width: 18%;
  margin: 1vh!important;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  border-width: 1px!important;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
.hide{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('#carousel-example-1z .small-slide').removeClass('carousel-item').addClass('hide');
    }
});
</script>
<div class="container-fluid main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
      <p><span class="txttop">Мы предоставляем  Вам сервис,<br>
а не просто продаем по вкусным ценам!</span></p>
      <p><span class="mainhtext">Примеры цен на металочерепицу от 50м<sup>2</sup>:</span></p>
      <a href=""><img src="img/arrowbottom.png" class="img-fluid imgarr"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div id="carousel-example-1z" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="bottom: -50px;">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="0" class="big-slide active" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="1" class="big-slide" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="2" class="big-slide" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="3" class="big-slide" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-1z" data-slide-to="4" class="small-slide" style="background:#fa7268;height: 5px;width: 25px;"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="margin-top: 2vh;">
      <!--First slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item active text-center big-slide">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито 1</p>
          <img src="img/sl1.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem" style="">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/sl2.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item text-center small-slide ">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито 2</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem" style="">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/First slide-->
      <!--Second slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item text-center big-slide ">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито 3</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Second slide-->
      <!--Third slide-->
      <div class="carousel-item text-center big-slide">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито 4</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem hiddobj">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item text-center big-slide ">
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито 5</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideritem">
          <p>Дешево и сердито</p>
          <img src="img/example.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="min-height: 140px!important;">
          <p>280 м<sup>2</sup></p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <p class="smlet">Китай Г 0,4мм</p>
          <a class="btnprod" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/Third slide-->
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img-fluid arrleft" src="img/arrowbottom.jpg"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-1z" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"><img class="img-fluid" src="img/arrowbottom.jpg"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <button class="btn_top">Хочу все цены</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тоесть мне нужно создать два слайдера? А с пролистыванием слайда нельзя

Comment: Если не хотите 2 слайдера то второй вариант к вашим услугам), просто пометьте слайд который вам не нужен на большой версии и с помощью Media Queries спрячте его)

Comment: Проблема в том, что содержимое самого слайда скрывается но этот слайд не пропадает, а становится невидимым

Comment: @Alexander посмотрите добавил еще 1 способ